# python argument doesn't work under virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to run a python script with an argument, like

```
import sys
src_name = sys.argv[1]
print "the argument is " + src_name
```

but I got the following error:

```
    print "the argument is " + src_name
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

how to deal with it?

Comment: Could it be that you are running python 3 in the virtualenv? If so, `print("the argument is " + src_name)`.

Comment: yes, you are right, why?

Comment: Because `print` is a function in python 3. Nice way to break python 2 code :-)